# chinese character encoding about django and highcharts(unicode utf8)

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, highcharts

We must provide series to highcharts, in views.py, the data is:

```
series_1 = [
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4056], 'name': '二手家具'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [3016], 'name': '家居百货'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [3765], 'name': '虚拟物品'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4056], 'name': '服饰箱包'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [3756], 'name': '闲置礼品'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4056], 'name': '图书/音乐/运动'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [3765], 'name': '农用品'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4052], 'name': '母婴/儿童用品'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4056], 'name': '二手手机'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4055], 'name': '美容护肤/化妆品'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4055], 'name': '二手笔记本'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4055], 'name': '电子数码'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [3765], 'name': '设备/办公用品'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4055], 'name': '台式电脑/网络'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4055], 'name': '老年用品'},
{'type': 'column', 'data': [4054], 'name': '家用电器'}]
```

the view fuction is :

```
def chart2(request):
context = {
    'series':series_1
}
return render(request, 'chart2.html', context)
```

the code of highcharts in chart2.html is:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Tongji',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'number'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        series:{{series|safe}}
    });
});
</script>>
```

when I run it, I only can see the messy code like this:
[image]

if I use unicode string like u'二手家具',the highcharts also has error like this:
[image]

I really don't know how to deal with this problem,please help me,thank you!

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Python 2.x or 3?

Comment: Looks like a problem with encoding in python, because Highcharts are building the chart from correct data properly - http://jsfiddle.net/oarLdbn8/